# setup.py how NOT to keep multiple version of packages

Tags: python-3.x, versioning, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I need some suggestion on my python setuptools deployment flows. Here is my current workflow.

1. The python name packages are stored in the remote git server with a setup.py (setuptools based) and it has a version number that gets update each time the code is changed.
2. The users would clone the git repos and run ./setup.py install to install the python package to system path (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-package/)
3. If there are any bugfix, updated code + version increment inside setup.py are done and changes are pushed to the git server.
4. The users do a git pull and run ./setup.py install again.

After step 4, usually import python module would point to the newest package, but I realize the older version of the same package still exists in dist-package/ I wonder how do we only keep the latest version of my package installed via setup.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` uninstalls previous version when upgrading a package. Instead of running `./setup.py` directly, ask users to use

```
pip install --upgrade .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is indeed a clean solution. The only thing I realized is that I have data_files in my setup.py and it’s not picking up by pip. Looks like I need to use package_data instead. Still trying to figure out how to convert from data_files to package_data